# Print path for object properties using recursion

Tags: jquery, recursion

I would like to print path for each proeprty in my object using recursion.

Suppose I have a long object, I would only like to print the properties which contains values.

My desired output:

```
{ "Level0.Level1.Level2.Level3.key": value }
{ "Level0.Level1.Level2.key": value }
```

I'm only interested to print those with assigned values. How can I modify my code below to achieve that.

My attempt so far:

```
function finalTraverse(data, path) {
    var myList = "<ul>";
    $.each(data, JSONRecurse);

    function JSONRecurse(key, value) {
        myList += "<li>";
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            myList += key + "<ul>";
            $.each(value, JSONRecurse);
            myList += "</ul>";
        } else {
            myList += "<a href='" + value + "'>" + key + "</a>";
            path = "{" + path + "." + key + ":";
            console.log(path);
        }
        myList += "</li>";
    }
    myList += "</ul>";
    $('body').append(myList);
}
```

Comment: There is no JSON in the above at all. You're dealing with a JavaScript object in memory and your goal is to output a list of properties. [JSON](http://json.org) is a specific *textual* representation used for data exchange.

Comment: I didn't specify the JSON object, because the json object may be different. In this code i have right now, i can print a JSON tree from my JSON object. What i want right now is to receive the full path of a key value object.

Comment: I didn't say you should. I said there **is** no JSON here at all. Just a JavaScript object. JSON is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's just clean Javascirpt. The data object inside finalTraverse, should be the data object/JSON object : function finalTraverse(data, path)

Comment: *"the data object/JSON object"* Again, there **is no JSON here**. There is no such thing as a JSON object except as **text**. It's just a JavaScript object.